# Verifying PHP Variable in JS Function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, backend

I'm basically trying to build a lockscreen for a website (not something overly complex) in which there is an input field(for the password)in a form, and a button(type submit). If the password is correct (if statements, because there are only 2 predefined passwords), the lockscreen would fade away, showing the rest of the website.

I tried to do this by checking the input in php and putting it in a variable. After this I tried to get the result in JS using json_encode($myvar). But it doesn't work, because whatever I write there I get the same error that the password is incorrect.

I'll attach the code here :

**index.php:**

```
<div id="lockscreen" style=" background: rgb(118,9,121); background: linear-gradient(10deg, rgba(118,9,121,1) 50%, rgba(244,0,255,1) 100%); z-index: 999; position: absolute; height: 275vh; overflow: hidden !important; position: fixed; ">
    <div class="lockContent">
        <form class="lockForm" method="POST" target="formRedirect">
        <input type="password" id="locktext" style=" color: white; width: 70%; height: 8vh; background-color: #80808087; " name="pass"></input>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-purple lockbutton" style=" height: 8vh; width: 10%; font-size: 85%; margin-top: -0.05%; " onclick="VerifyUser()"><i class="fas fa-key"></i>
        </button>

<?php
include 'assets/php/myphp.php';

$lockPass = $_POST['pass'];
$resultLock = CheckInput($lockPass);

?>


    </form>

            <script type="text/javascript">

        var result = <?php echo json_encode($resultLock); ?>;
        var Lockscreen = $("#lockscreen");

        function VerifyUser(){
            if(result == true)
            {
                Lockscreen.fadeOut(3000);
                alert("Welcome !");
            } 
                else alert("Incorrect password !");
        }

    </script>

    </div>
    <div class="lockWelcomeCont">
        <h2 class="text-uppercase lockWelcome" style=" font-size: 135%; "> Gain access by entering the password in the field below.</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="lockHintCont">
        <h4 class="text-uppercase lockHint" style=" margin-top: 2%; font-size: 14px; color: #ffffff; font-weight: 700; "> * The password is case sensitive.</h4>
    </div>

</div>
```

**myphp.php**

```
//rest of the code, nothing wrong here

function CheckInput($input){

if($input == "SPV" || $input == "TEACHERS"){
    return true;
} else {return false;}
```

}

What is wrong, what could I do ? 
Thank you all in advance ! :)

** Edit: I’m looking for a solution without using AJAX **

Comment: Make a separate php file that only does the login check.  If the login is successful, return a 200.  If it is unsuccessful, return a 401 Unauthorized.  Then all your page needs to do is make the ajax request, and check the status code to know if login was valid.  There is no need to render the response to a hidden variable on the page, in html or javascript, to do this.

Comment: Otherwise if you are doing a normal form submit for the login, the backend should handle forwarding the user back to the login, or on into the application, depending upon the success of the login.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use onClick to verify a POST action using a submit action.
To do this you must use an asynchronous call, e.g. ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you would want to implement [ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) here.

However, what I think the problem in your code is you're validating the user with `onclick()` and even if the form is submitted, it will be after the function call. Without AJAX, nothing is coming from the server asynchronously, so the value of `$lockPass` will always remain the same it was on page load, which was false.

In theory, if after the form is submitted and the user remains on the same page, you can check for $_POST data  and verify the user if $_POST data exists. Otherwise, do nothing.

Try the following code:

```
<div id="lockscreen" style=" background: rgb(118,9,121); background: linear-gradient(10deg, rgba(118,9,121,1) 50%, rgba(244,0,255,1) 100%); z-index: 999; position: absolute; height: 275vh; overflow: hidden !important; position: fixed; ">
    <div class="lockContent">
        <form class="lockForm" method="POST" target="formRedirect">
        <input type="password" id="locktext" style=" color: white; width: 70%; height: 8vh; background-color: #80808087; " name="pass"></input>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-purple lockbutton" style=" height: 8vh; width: 10%; font-size: 85%; margin-top: -0.05%; "><i class="fas fa-key"></i>
        </button>

<?php
include 'assets/php/myphp.php';

$lockPass = $_POST['pass'];
if(isset($_POST['pass'])){
    $resultLock = CheckInput($lockPass);
}else{
    $resultLock = "NotYet";
}

?>


    </form>

            <script type="text/javascript">

        var result = <?php echo json_encode($resultLock); ?>;
    if(result != "NotYet"){
        var Lockscreen = $("#lockscreen");

        function VerifyUser(){
            if(result == true)
            {
                Lockscreen.fadeOut(3000);
                alert("Welcome !");
            } 
                else alert("Incorrect password !");
        }
        VerifyUser(); //Call the function on page load, not on click
    }

    </script>

    </div>
    <div class="lockWelcomeCont">
        <h2 class="text-uppercase lockWelcome" style=" font-size: 135%; "> Gain access by entering the password in the field below.</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="lockHintCont">
        <h4 class="text-uppercase lockHint" style=" margin-top: 2%; font-size: 14px; color: #ffffff; font-weight: 700; "> * The password is case sensitive.</h4>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use AJAX, see the code below. This will however refresh your page and relies on POST data. If you want the page to unlock without reloading, then you will have to make a AJAX request.

```
 <?php
include 'assets/php/myphp.php';

$lockPass = isset($_POST['pass']) ? $_POST['pass'] : "";
$resultLock = CheckInput($lockPass);

if(isset($_POST['pass'])): //only add javascript if POST was executed.
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var result = <?php echo json_encode($resultLock); ?>;
    var Lockscreen = $("#lockscreen");

    function VerifyUser(){
        if(result == true)
        {
            Lockscreen.fadeOut(3000);
            alert("Welcome !");
        } 
        else alert("Incorrect password !");
    }

</script>
<?php endif; ?>
<div id="lockscreen" style=" background: rgb(118,9,121); background: linear-gradient(10deg, rgba(118,9,121,1) 50%, rgba(244,0,255,1) 100%); z-index: 999; position: absolute; height: 275vh; overflow: hidden !important; position: fixed; ">
    <div class="lockContent">
        <form class="lockForm" method="POST" name="loginForm">
            <input type="password" id="locktext" style=" color: white; width: 70%; height: 8vh; background-color: #80808087; " name="pass"></input>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-purple lockbutton" style=" height: 8vh; width: 10%; font-size: 85%; margin-top: -0.05%; "><i class="fas fa-key"></i>
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="lockWelcomeCont">
        <h2 class="text-uppercase lockWelcome" style=" font-size: 135%; "> Gain access by entering the password in the field below.</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="lockHintCont">
        <h4 class="text-uppercase lockHint" style=" margin-top: 2%; font-size: 14px; color: #ffffff; font-weight: 700; "> * The password is case sensitive.</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT AJAX**

To use ajax, make another file and name it `ajaxlogin.php`

```
<?php
include 'assets/php/myphp.php';

$lockPass = isset($_POST['pass']) ? $_POST['pass'] : "";
$resultLock = CheckInput($lockPass);

return $resultLock;
?>
```

and in your main file, (I have not tested this code)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var Lockscreen = $("#lockscreen");

    function VerifyUser(result){
        if(result == true)
        {
            Lockscreen.fadeOut(3000);
            alert("Welcome !");
        } 
        else alert("Incorrect password !");
    }

    $.post( "ajaxlogin.php", function( data ) {
      VerifyUser(data);
    });
</script>
<div id="lockscreen" style=" background: rgb(118,9,121); background: linear-gradient(10deg, rgba(118,9,121,1) 50%, rgba(244,0,255,1) 100%); z-index: 999; position: absolute; height: 275vh; overflow: hidden !important; position: fixed; ">
    <div class="lockContent">
        <form class="lockForm" method="POST" name="loginForm">
            <input type="password" id="locktext" style=" color: white; width: 70%; height: 8vh; background-color: #80808087; " name="pass"></input>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-purple lockbutton" style=" height: 8vh; width: 10%; font-size: 85%; margin-top: -0.05%; "><i class="fas fa-key"></i>
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="lockWelcomeCont">
        <h2 class="text-uppercase lockWelcome" style=" font-size: 135%; "> Gain access by entering the password in the field below.</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="lockHintCont">
        <h4 class="text-uppercase lockHint" style=" margin-top: 2%; font-size: 14px; color: #ffffff; font-weight: 700; "> * The password is case sensitive.</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```